# React, Node Express, Mysql registration form stuck

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm learning how to connect my front end to a database using middleware and trying to clone a waiver/registration form for a project my buddy gave me.

I can manually input data from the code editor to Mysql database but once I try to link it to the front end I get nothing, I'm completely stumped, can't really find any updated documentation on Node express syntax and mysql.

Here is my server and database code:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: "",
  database: "cloneDataBase",
});

app.use(express.json());

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/api/get", (req, res) => {
  const sqlGet = "SELECT * FROM customer_registration";
  db.query(sqlGet, (error, result) => {
    res.send(result);
  });
});

app.post("/api/post", (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, lastName, email, phone, nickName } = req.body;
  const sqlInsert =
    "INSERT INTO customer_registration (firstName, lastName, email, phone, nickName) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
  db.query(
    sqlInsert,
    [firstName, lastName, email, phone, nickName],
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  );
});
```

heres my registration form.

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./NewCustomer.css";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import axios from "axios";

const initialState = {
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "",
  email: "",
  phone: "",
  nickName: "",
};

export default function NewCustomer() {
  const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

  const { firstName, lastName, email, phone, nickName } = state;

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefalut();
    if (!firstName || !lastName || !email || !phone || !nickName) {
      toast.error("Please Provide value into each input field");
    } else {
      axios
        .post("http://localhost:3001/api/post", {
          firstName,
          lastName,
          email,
          phone,
          nickName,
        })
        .then(() => {
          setState({
            firstName: "",
            lastName: "",
            email: "",
            phone: "",
            nickName: "",
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => toast.error(err.response.data));
      setTimeout(() => navigate.push("/"), 500);
    }
  };

  // const handleInputChange = (e) => {
  //   const { name, value } = e.target;
  //   setState({ ...state, [name]: value });
  // };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="new-customer-reg">
        <Link to="/">
          <button className="center-button-startover">Start Over</button>
        </Link>
        <div className="form-in">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="new-customer-form">
            <label for="firstName">First Name*</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="first_name"
              required
              // value={firstName}
              // onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <br />
            <label for="lastName">Last Name*</label>
            <input
              type="text"
              name="last_name"
              required
              // value={lastName}
              // onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <br />
            <label for="email">Email*</label>
            <input
              type="email"
              className="email"
              required
              // value={email}
              // onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <br />
            <label for="phone">Phone*</label>
            <input
              type="tel"
              className="phone"
              required
              // value={phone}
              // onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <br />
            <label for="nickName">Nickname</label>
            <input
              type=" text"
              className="nickname"
              // value={nickName}
              // onChange={handleInputChange}
            />
            <div className="input-with-optional">
              <span className="nick-helper">
                (optional) This will be displayed instead of your first name.
              </span>
              <br />
            </div>
            <button onSubmit={handleSubmit} type="submit" className="regi">
              Register
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}enter code here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to send a response from your POST route handler. For example:

```js
res.send('Customer created')
```

Additionally, in your frontend you have a typo (`preventDefalut`) which will make your code crash.

Comment: I added that in, and crazy enough on postman under the x-www-form-urlencoded i was able to input data, but on my NewCustomer.js file, when I input the data, it just reloads the page and does nothing in connection to the database.

Comment: That would be a different problem then - you call `preventDefalut` which doesn't exist due to a spelling error, should be `preventDefault`. Therefore execution stops at that point and the request is never sent, but also the default isn't prevented and therefore the form is submitted in the regular way which is what you perceive as "page reload". If you'd look into your devtools console (with "Preserve log" enabled) you should see this mistake shown to you.

Comment: I feel so dumb for making such a simple mistake. I keep discovering new errors after every fix!

Comment: Typos happen to everyone, that's where good linters can really help and where it's important to know where to look for the pieces of information the computer gives you back that point towards the source of the problem.